# Проблема с парсером на python при выводе

Tags: python, python-3.x, bs4

Добрый день дорогие дамы и господа ! Вот сам мой код !

```
#Парсер v2 by Raha
import traceback
import requests
import dateparser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.ok: # 200  ## 403 404
        return r.text
    print(r.status_code)


def get_page_link(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    title =soup.find('h1',{'class':'roboto'}).text
    link_containers=soup.findAll('div',{'class':'cat_news_item'})


    counter = 0
    links_rcv = []
    for link_container in link_containers:
        a_tag = link_container .find("a")
        # Если нашел
        if a_tag:
            link = a_tag.get("href")
            links_rcv.append(f'https://www.zakon.kz{link}')
            #print(f'https://www.zakon.kz{link}')
        else:
            counter += 1

    return links_rcv


def get_context_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


def get_context_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    item_content= mainblock=soup.find('div',{'class':'fullnews white_block'})
    item_title= title=mainblock.find('h1').text
    item_datetime= mainblock.find('span',{'class':'news_date'}).text
    item_text= text_contents=mainblock.findAll('p')

    if item_content is None:
        item_content1= mainblock1=soup.find('div',{'class':'full_story'})
        item_title1= title1=mainblock1.find('title',{'class':'full_story'}).text
        item_datetime1= mainblock1.find('div',{'class':'news_date'}).text
        item_text1= text_contents1 =mainblock1.findAll('p',{'class':'MsoNormal'})
        return (item_title1,item_datetime1,item_text1)


    #datetime=dateparser.parse(datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H']) #Конвентирует формат времени удобный в SQL



def main():
    url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/news/'
    links_rcv = get_page_link(get_html(url))
    for i in links_rcv:
        try:
            print(get_context_data(get_context_html(i)))
        except:
            print(f'Ошибка на странице: {i}')
            print(traceback.format_exc())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

При **выводе** я не понимаю почему выводится **None**

Comment: Это инструкции для сайта у которого разная структура страниц новостей.И для этого я использовал этот пример инструкции с этого сайта http://code.activestate.com/recipes/59892-testing-if-a-variable-is-defined/ первый пример

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_context_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    mainblock = soup.find('div',{'class':'fullnews white_block'})  # < Получаем контекст.

    if mainblock is not None:  # < Если контекст не пуст, продолжаем разбор.
        item_title = mainblock.find('h1').text
        item_datetime = mainblock.find('span',{'class':'news_date'}).text
        item_text = mainblock.findAll('p')
    else:  # < Иначе получаем и разбираем контекст другого типа.
        mainblock = soup.find('div',{'class':'full_story'})
        item_title = mainblock.find('title',{'class':'full_story'}).text
        item_datetime = mainblock.find('div',{'class':'news_date'}).text
        item_text = mainblock.findAll('p',{'class':'MsoNormal'})            

    return (item_title,item_datetime,item_text)  # < Возвращаем результат, вне зависимости от типа страницы.
```

Comment: Можно вопрос?А почему в else еще добавили инструкции? Можете обьяснить

Comment: @r4khic Добавил в Ответ. Они не новые, это конструкции из вашего кода.

Comment: Это я понял,но как я понял из сайта вроде добавление в инструкций в else не обязательно.

Comment: Про "инструкции с сайта", я понятия не имею. Я могу придумать десяток вариантов решения вашей задачи. Я исходил из логики вашего кода и немного его оптимизировал. Вы пытались, сначала полностью разобрать контекст первого типа и только потом проверить, правильный он или нет. В моем примере, сначала выполняем проверку контекста, потом разбираем нужный.

Comment: И это не говоря о том, что вы кучу лишних переменных насозавали `item_content1` и прочие `*1`.

Comment: @r4khic Обновил ответ. По правилам хорошего тона: `if нормальное продолжение else: идем другим путем`.